# Table in sys.objects but not in table list

Tags: sql-server, azure

Cant seem to figure out why sys.objects says I have a table that clearly isnt there.

As you can see its not me being dumb and not paying attention to schema differences.

This is an Azure db if that helps

[image]
[image]

Comment: Right click `Databases` and click `Refresh` maybe?

Comment: @charlieface did that already, but thank you

Comment: Are you *sure* the query window is connected to the same server? It is possible to be connected to a different one than the Explorer

Comment: @charlieface I added a second screen grab of the db name of the editor. In azure you can really only connect to one at a time (i think you know this though).

Comment: Looks like you've actually got two servers there in the Explorer (hard to tell behind the red scribble), and `ApplyNow_DEV` appears to be the database name, not the server. How about you right click on the correct server and click `Query From Current Connection`

Comment: @charlieface in the very same editor I ran SELECT @@ServerName and it returned the server i was expecting. I swear to you that I have crossed all my i's and dotted all my t's here in terms of GUI brain farts.

Comment: or at least i hope so? LOL

Comment: Then the Explorer must be lying. Did you try closing and reopening SSMS? Barring that, something really screwy with the system tables, perhaps run checks `DBCC CHECKCATALOG WITH NO_INFOMSGS`

Comment: @charlieface I completely closed and reran query - still showing its there. Geez this is very strange lol

Comment: Is the object explorer connected with the same database user?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yessir

Comment: OOooooo I figured it out. Its an external table. Ive never needed to use one of these so I didnt think to look in the sub category for external tables. It was in fact a GUI brain fart. I guess ill go read what external tables are used for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an external table, which I had no previous experience with

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There is a separate directory under Tables where External Tables are located.

Follow this path in Object Explorer in SSMS: **Databases -> [Specific database] -> Tables -> External Tables**

[image]